# Why does including the msbuild OutputPath option cause MetadataWorkspace error when building Silverlight/WCF RIA sln?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, msbuild, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services

[specific version numbers of items related to this issue are included at the end of the text]

When building the Foo.sln (SL4 with WCF/RIA services) with the following msbuild command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild SNSC.sln /nologo /p:configuration=release /p:OutputPath=..\..\output\Foo /t:Rebuild
```

... I receive the following error:

> "C:\SourceCode2\prod\current\Silverlight\Foo.sln" (Rebuild target) (1)
>   -> "C:\SourceCode2\prod\current\Silverlight\Foo.Web.Data\Foo.Web.Data.csproj"
>   (Rebuild target) (2) ->
>   "C:\SourceCode2\prod\current\Silverlight\Foo.Fha\Foo.Fha.csproj"
>   (default target) (3:2) -> (CreateRiaClientFiles target) ->
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(303,5):
>   error : **Failed to get the MetadataWorkspace for the DbContext type**
>   'Foo.Web.Data.Fha.CoreDbContext'.
>   [C:\SourceCode2\prod\current\Silverligh t\Foo.Fha\Foo.Fha.csproj]
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v4.0\Microsoft.Ria.Client.targets(303,5):
>   error : **Failed to get the MetadataWorkspace for the DbContext type**
>   'Foo.Web.Data.LoanCorrespondence.CoreDbContext'.
>   [C:\SourceCode2\prod\cur rent\Silverlight\Foo.Fha\Foo.Fha.csproj]

However, when I remove the OutputPath option (keeping the rest of the command the same):

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild SNSC.sln /nologo /p:configuration=release /t:Rebuild
```

...the build succeeds (albeit with 77 warnings).  And of course it compiles with no issue in VS2010.

Why does the inclusion of the OutputPath option cause this exception?

Specifics:

```
    * attempted on 2 different 64bit machines with same result
    * win7 OS
    * msbuild: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild
    * Silverlight 4 with WCF RIA
```

Comment: OutputPath is eventually used to create OutDir so you may want to try by using that variable instead.

Comment: This issue exists when Outdir and OutputPath are used.